# Strange slowdown when using openmp

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, openmp

I am trying to increase performance of a rather complex iteration algorithm by parallelizing matrix multiplication, which is being called on each iteration.
The algorithm takes 500 iterations and approximately 10 seconds. But after parallelizing matrix multiplication it slows down to 13 seconds.
However, when I tested matrix multiplication of the same dimension alone, there was an increase in speed. (I am talking about 100x100 matrices.)

Finally, I switched off any parallelizing inside the algorithm and added on each iteration the following piece of code, which does absolutely nothing and presumably shouldn't take long:

```
int j;

#pragma omp parallel for private(j)

for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
j = i;
```

And again, there is a 30% slowdown comparing to the same algorithm without this piece of code.

Thus, calling any parallelization using openmp 500 times inside the main algorithm somehow slows things down. This behavior looks very strange to me, anybody has any clues what the problem is?

The main algorithm is being called by a desktop application, compiled by VS2010, Win32 Release.
I work on Intel Core i3 (parallelization creates 4 threads), 64 bit Windows 7.

Here is a structure of a program:

```
int internal_method(..)

{
...//no openmp here


 // the following code does nothing, has nothing to do with the rest of the program  and shouldn't take long,
 // but somehow adding of this code caused a 3 sec slowdown of the Huge_algorithm()
 double sum;
 #pragma omp parallel for private(sum)
 for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    sum = i*i*i / (1.0 + i*i*i*i);

...//no openmp here
}


int Huge_algorithm(..)
{

 ...//no openmp here

    for (int i = 0; i < 500; i++)
    {
     .....// no openmp

     internal_method(..);

     ......//no openmp
    }

...//no openmp here
}
```

So, the final point is:
calling the parallel piece of code 500 times alone (when the rest of the algorithm is omitted) takes less than 0.01 sec, but when you call it 500 times inside a huge algorithm it causes 3 sec delay of the entire algorithm.
And what I don't understand is how the small parallel part affects the rest of the algorithm?

Comment: Just to make sure, how do you measure execution time? I've seen a lot of OpenMP and MT related questions here on SO where people measure CPU time instead of wall-clock time in parallel programs. Other thing is: entering and exiting parallel regions is relatively expensive (even with modern pooling OMP runtimes).

Comment: I am using wall-clock time, the desktop application actually measures the time. This is true about entering and exiting parallel regions, but I have 500 enters and exits and a 3 sec slowdown - this doesn't add up.

Comment: 3 seconds for 500 parallel regions gives an average of 6 ms overhead per parallel region, including threads wake-up at the beginning and synchronisation wait at the end. Unfortunately I was unable to find information on how long it takes to wake up a thread from Win32 thread pool but 6 ms is close to the scheduling interval on most x86/x64 OSes. I should do some measurements whenever time permits.

Comment: @Hristo Iliev: Really nice comment :)

Answer (score 2):

For 10 iterations and a simple assignment, I guess there is too much OpenMP overhead compared to the computation itself. What looks lightweight here is actually managing and synchronizing multiple threads which may not even come from a thread pool. There might be some locking involved, and I don't know how good MSVC is at estimating whether to parallelize at all.

Try with bigger loop bodies or a bigger amount of iterations (say 1024*1024 iterations, just for starters).

---

Example OpenMP Magick:

```
#pragma omp parallel for private(j)
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    j = i;
```

This might be *approximately* expanded by a compiler to:

```
const unsigned __cpu_count = __get_cpu_count();
const unsigned __j  = alloca (sizeof (unsigned) * __cpu_count);
__thread *__threads = alloca (sizeof (__thread) * __cpu_count);
for (unsigned u=0; u!=__cpu_count; ++u) {
    __init_thread (__threads+u);
    __run_thread ([u]{for (int i=u; i<10; i+=__cpu_count)
                          __j[u] = __i;}); // assume lambdas
}

for (unsigned u=0; u!=__cpu_count; ++u)
    __join (__threads+u);
```

with `__init_thread()`, `__run_thread()` and `__join()` being non-trivial function that invoke certain system calls.

In case thread-pools are used, you would replace the first `alloca()` by something like `__pick_from_pool()` or so.

(note this, names and emitted code, was all imaginary, actual implementation will look different)

---

Regarding your updated question:

You seem to be parallelizing at the wrong granularity. Put as much workload as possible in a thread, so instead of

```
 for (...) {
     #omp parallel ...
     for (...) {} 
 }
```

try

```
 #omp parallel ...
 for (...) {
     for (...) {} 
 }
```

Rule of thumb: Keep workloads big enough per thread so as to reduce relative overhead.

Comment: MSVC implements OpenMP thread teams using thread pools but still the overhead is quite large.

Comment: @Hristo Iliev: Interesting info. Do you have any further links on MSVC's implementation details?

Comment: @phresnel, thanks. Parallelizing 10 iterations of simple j=i or sum = i*i*i / (1.0 + i*i*i*i) is clearly not the way to improve the performance. But my point is that how 500 calls to a very short parallelized cycle (which does nothing and has nothing to do with the rest of the algorithm) can cause a 3 sec slowdown of the whole program?

Comment: @user1523105: That's what my last edit is about. You have a big, non-parallel loop, where each iteration, one by another, will invoke an inner-loop that is parallel. I.e., instead of starting x threads once to work on 500*10, you 500 times start x threads to work on 10 entities.

Comment: And this can really cause 3 sec delay? Because calling 500 times an inner parallel loop alone (without the rest of the algorithm) takes less than 0.01 sec. I cannot understand this inconsistency.

Comment: @phresnel, my best reference is the assembler output from MSVC and IDA for the run-time libraries. But still, the fact that MSVC uses thread pools is mentioned [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163717.aspx).

Comment: @user1523105: Yeah, because of the overhead. Look again at my example what might be substituted for an innocent looking `#omp parallel for ...`, compare that overhead to ten assignments in the innter loop (`j = i;`), and consider that you are doing this 500 times.

Comment: @phresnel: Another small point. I tried to put absolutely the same parallel code into another 500 iteration algorithm (a similar one, but faster). I got a slowdown by 0.5 sec, from 1 sec to 1.5 sec. And again, without any algorithm, 500 times the same parallel code takes close to 0 sec. Can the overhead of paralleling depend this much on what happens between parallel pieces of code?

Comment: @user1523105: I can't give a definite answer, but effectively, with 4 cores, you are (by concept) starting/stopping 2000 threads in total, for each of them, your program has to wait ("join"). Running a loop 10 times and assigning two or three times inside it is only a tiny fraction of workload, compared to organising threads.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe just j=i is not high-yield for core-cpu bandwith. maybe you should try something more yielding calculation. (for exapmle taking i*i*i*i*i*i and dividing it by i+i+i)

are you running this on multi-core cpu or gpu?

Comment: multi-core cpu (4 cores) I just don't understand why a trivial openmp parallelized piece of code can cause such a huge slowdown. I found using profiler that there was a slowdown of other methods having nothing to do with parallelizing

Comment: can you try matrix multiplication with an additional power of 3 calculation and tell the difference of speed up?

Comment: @user1523105, there are tons of OpenMP performance related questions on StackOverflow. None of them could be answered without showing us some sample code from the actual algorithm. I would say that you should also run your code with a tool like Intel Threads Checker and look for caching problems like false sharing.

Comment: Thanks, Hristo. I sketched the structure of a program, if this of any help.